# MailChimp preview overrides link styles

Tags: templates, editor, mailchimp

I've run across a problem when creating a custom template for MailChimp - when editing links inside the emails content MailChimp overrides their styles. Here's a part of the template,

```
<a mc:edit="cta_link" target="_blank" href="*|CUSTOM_URL|*" style="font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif !important; font-size: 11px; color: #000000 !important; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; padding-bottom: 1px;">Read more</a>
```

As you can see I've also added *!important* rules to some of the styles to try and avoid any overrides but with no effect. I've switched between having a static example href src and the MailChimp custom url variable, doesn't seem to make any difference.
After updating the link the font changes to a default Times typeface.
Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a full dump of the mail chimp page that is overriding the styles? There is a possibility that the mail chimp styles also have !important attached at which point it becomes more a matter of which style is implemented first. If you use chrome you can inspect the element and see which styles are being used and which are being overridden.

Comment: I can't replicate this error. I put this in a custom template and it behaved as expected. Can you send yourself a test email and post the html content?

Comment: Here's the full template code. Appreciate if you could talke a look. http://pastebin.com/cuZCmrhz

Answer (score 0):

4 years later and it's still happening.

The styles you apply to a link element are overridden by the global link styles.

My solution: insert a span tag inside the link.

```
<a mc:edit="cta_link" target="_blank" href="*|CUSTOM_URL|*"><span style="font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif !important; font-size: 11px; color: #000000 !important; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important; text-transform: uppercase !important; padding-bottom: 1px;">Read more</a>
```